# salt stack: use state jinja variables in template

Tags: saltstack, template

What I'd like to do is generate multiple configuration files for each openvpn user.
I have the IP address and additional configuration in pillar.

For example:

```
openvpn:
  - user1:
    ip: 1.2.3.4
    config:
      - line1
      - line2
```

In the SLS I'd like to do something like:

```
{% for vpnuser in salt['pillar.get']('openvpn') %}
/etc/openvpn/ccd/{{ vpnuser }}:
  file.managed:
    - template: jinja
    - source: salt://openvpn/ccdtemplate
{% endfor %}
```

and in the ccdtemplate I'd like to generate the config depending on the user and the config data for this user stored in pillar.

But therefor I would need to know the content of the variable 'vpnuser' from the state.

Is it possible to pass variables from a state to the jinja template?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass any value you need to the template by using the `defaults` keyword. In your case, this would be:

```
{% for vpnuser in salt['pillar.get']('openvpn') %}
/etc/openvpn/ccd/{{ vpnuser }}:
  file.managed:
    - template: jinja
    - source: salt://openvpn/ccdtemplate
    - defaults:
        vpnuser: {{ vpnuser }}
{% endfor %}
```

This is documented in http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html

Comment: You can use the `context` option the same way as `defaults`, which is a little confusing. They try to clarify like so: "The general best practice is to place default values in `defaults`, with conditional overrides going into `context`."